# Does anybody know any troubles with deploying Visual C++ library using XCopy?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, mfc, crt

We need to deploy Visual C++ library. We have tried deploy this libraries using Merge Modules, but uninstall became too slow (about 10-20 minutes). So we've decided to deploy this libraries using [XCopy method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235291.aspx). Does anybody know any troubles with deploying Visual C++ library using XCopy?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of private Visual C++ runtime libraries they won't be updated by windows update so this eventually could bring security breach.

Another problem with deployment is that different versions of Windows search libraries in different folders. Windows 2000 expects dlls to be in application folder but since Vista and later on vc runtime libraries should be in Microsoft.VC90.CRT subfolder. It's not an issue if your app is for private or corporate use but should be considered when you have 'external' customers.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Yes, it's bad, but it isn't fatal. User can install the libraries by himself (including by installing other soft). In this case our application will use this global version of the libraries.
Yes, SbS isn't deployed in Windows 2000 box. But we haven't supported Win2000 for 1 year so it isn't trouble.